# jQuery tabs does not working on Android mobile device.

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I'm working on my website which contains *tabs*. The code works great on desktops but on android mobile devices (Android Chrome and Android Firefox browsers) **the *tabs* are not switching**. Every other part of the website works fine on desktop and mobile, except the above mentioned issue. No errors showing in the consoles. Here's the code:

**jQuery/CSS/HTML**

```js
// tabs
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e) {
    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    // Show/Hide Tabs
    $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).siblings().slideUp(400);
    $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).delay(400).slideDown(400);

    // Change/remove current tab to active
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
/* Clearfix */

.tab-links:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}

ul.tab-links {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.tab-links li {
  margin: 0px 14px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.tab-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #757575;
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
}

.tab-links a:hover {
  color: #212121;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li.active a,
li.active a:hover {
  color: #F44436;
}


/*----- Content of Tabs -----*/

.tab-content {
  padding: 5px;
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}

.tab.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tab-links">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Summary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Info</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
      <p>Nulla fermentum nibh sit</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In place of click use touch and than let me know

Comment: Tried it, doesn't solved the issue. After replacing 'click' the script stopped working on desktop too. No errors in the console.

Comment: It works ok for me on Android. Is your click handler actually getting called?